# Overflow CSS - overflow-wrap: break-word;

Tags: html, css

Does `overflow-wrap: break-word;` **really guarantee me 100%** that there will be no overflow of **inline elements** (such as text) or do I have to consider other factors?

I refuse to let the overflow not be predictable, **I need to guarantee my customers.**

Comment: `overflow-wrap: break-word` will only prevent overflow for [text content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element#text_content).

Comment: I think that's the important thing, isn't it, since overflow usually happens with text, right?

Comment: Not always, but yes, mostly with text.

Comment: No, overflow happens with anything. [`<div style="overflow-y: auto; max-height: 100px"><div style="height: 1000px; width: 300px"></div></div>` will show a scrollbar](https://jsfiddle.net/ka2sb3z8/) with no text. It's just that `overflow-wrap: break-word` only works with text.

Comment: Great @Heretic Monkey, in your experience, is it good to always put overflow* in case of overflow to avoid problems in the future?

Comment: @Daniel No, the best practice is not to have any `overflow` unless intentional. Debugging overflow is made easy by setting a solid `outline` on `*` to see which element is causing the overflow.

Comment: Depends on the requirements of the person paying me to build the website :) and the designer/UX person, I suppose, if there is one. But yes, generally, we design things to handle overflow nicely.

Comment: I understand @Kameron but sometimes the content is not predictable, you don't know how much a container will have content and that's what is difficult to debug, in fact that's what my question refers to :(, imagine input of the user

Comment: @Daniel Please consider adding an [example] in a `<>` Stack Snippet so we can see what you are referring too and give you the best possible answer.